# Can adjusting handlebar height help reduce hand numbness?

Tags: handlebars, bike-setup, comfort

Riding my mountain bike on the roads in experiencing tingling and numbness in my hands, especially the left, after 10-15 minutes. It's intermittent and I can disperse it by wiggling my hand when it's safe to take one hand of the bars for a few seconds.

I wondered if adjusting the handlebar height might help? I recently corrected my saddle height by raising it about 3" but maybe that puts more weight on my wrists as I lean further forward?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best "fix" for this, a type of glove with ribbed padding, is no longer available (that I know of).

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Specialized sells some with that type of padding.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't the first to have problems with numbness riding, so take heart. You raised the saddle a lot, and that will transfer weight to the front of the bike via your hands. You have several options:

Pre-Ride:
* Buy some cycling gloves
* Raise the handlebars until they are comfortable (maybe an inch or so a ride)

During the Ride:
*Move your hands around the bar every so often. Road bikes have a lot of places to grip, and this is one of the reasons

If these don't work, then you could go to a bike shop and inquire about a simple fit. You could also do the same and look up how online.

*My guess is that the reach from the seat to the handlebars is to short and to steep, which is great for a mountain bike that needs to be yanked around. It isn't the best for the stability and endurance needed in a road bike.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet, Look up Ergon grips. They have a platform for your palm that alleviates the pressure and constriction put on your capillaries from the pressure your body puts on your hands
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ergon%20grips

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my commuter bike. I installed the Ergon grips with the pads angled up a little to keep my wrists flatter instead of bent back. That and better padded gloves really helped.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. Nice start, good to see you here